# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, datetime, pdo

I get this error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (06-28-2014 07:43:58 ) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character' in /Users/matt/Desktop/Likes/forgot/activate.php on line 17

When trying to do this

```
//DB query
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT token_created_at from reset WHERE token = :urltoken");
$stmt->bindValue(':urltoken', $_GET['token']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $token_created_at = $row['token_created_at'];
}

//Remove after testing
echo $token_created_at;

$my_dt = new DateTime($token_created_at);

//Modify error
$expires_at = $my_dt->modify('+1 hour');

//Return current time to match
$current_time = date('m-d-Y H:i:s ', time());
```

Line 17 is `$my_dt = new DateTime($token_created_at);` and this is my time format `06-28-2014 07:43:58`.

This is how I generate `token_created_at`, `$time_gen = date('m-d-Y H:i:s ', time());`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The date string you're passing is [not supported](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) by the DateTime parser. You must create a DateTime object by using [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). This method allows you to specify the custom format when creating a new DateTime object:

```
$my_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $token_created_at);
```

If you're still getting an error that means that your `$token_created_at` is not in the format you specified:

```
$now = date('m-d-Y H:i:s'); //string(19) "06-28-2014 15:00:47"

var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $now));
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-06-28 15:00:47"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

**Edit**

I see your problem - the format string has a space after `s`. The format strings must match **exactly**:

```
$my_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s ', $token_created_at);
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated my answer

```
function date_time( $date ) {
    if( $date == "" ){
        return "";
    } else {
        // echo $date;
        $my_date  = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'm-d-Y H:i:s', $date );
        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($my_date);
        // echo '</pre>';
        $new_date = $my_date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
        return $new_date;
    }
}

$save = date_time('06-28-2014 07:43:58');
$my_dt = new DateTime( $save );

//Modify error
$expires_at = $my_dt->modify('+1 hour');
$expires_date = $my_dt->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

echo $expires_date;
//Return current time to match
$current_time = date('m-d-Y H:i:s', time());
echo $current_time;
```

Comment: @user302975 Yes it should be a variable. You can assign value to variable & pass it to date_time function. It hard coded this for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$token_created_at = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y H:i:s", $token_created_at);
$my_dt = new DateTime($token_created_at->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$expires_at = $my_dt->modify('+1 hour');
```

This will generates

```
2014-06-28 08:43:58
```