# DateTime timezone not found in database

Tags: php, datetime

Did anyone else had this strange problem?
Error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct():  Failed to parse time string (01/18/2016
>   00:00 AM America/New_York)  at position 17 (A): The timezone could not
>   be found in the database'
>
> Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (01/18/2016 00:00 AM America/New_York) at position 17 (A): The
>   timezone could not be found in the database

Original PHP Code:

```
$datetime = new DateTime(trim(html_entity_decode($this->input->post('publish_date').' '.$_POST['schedule_time'].' '.$_POST['schedule_meridian'] . ' ' .$_POST['schedule_timezone'])));
$date = $datetime->format('D, d M Y H:i:s O');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::\_\_construct(): Failed to parse time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466794/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-exception-with-message-datetime-construct)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I afraid you've created DateTime object like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('01/18/2016 00:00 AM America/New_York');
```

That is not a [supported](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)/valid datetime format!

If you want to create a DateTime object from another format you must call [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead, look:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$strdate  = '01/18/2016 00:00 AM';
$date     = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i A', $strdate, $timezone);
```

**PHP doc states:**

> DateTime::createFromFormat / date_create_from_format — Returns new
>   *DateTime* object formatted according to the specified format