# Why PHP does not parse “BRST” dates anymore?

Tags: php, datetime

BRST refers to "Brasília Summer Time"

Before version 7.0.26, PHP could parse this string without any problem:

```
$date = DateTime("Mon Jan 01 20:00:00 BRST 2017");
```

After that version, PHP returns:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to 
parse time string (Mon Jan 01 20:00:00 BRST 2017) at position 4 (J): 
The timezone could not be found in the database in /in/c6K56:5
Stack trace:
#0 /in/c6K56(5): DateTime->__construct('Mon Jan 01 20:0...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /in/c6K56 on line 5

Process exited with code 255.
```

I searched in changelogs, but I couldn't find any explanation for that.

Here is the example:

https://3v4l.org/c6K56#v7026

Comment: Just to make it clear: You are not searching for a solution / workarround, but for an explanation instead, right?

Comment: possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861317/datetime-timezone-not-found-in-database

Comment: Our REST API receives date parameters from many mobile apps. Some apps, I guess by device settings, send date strings with "BRST". After updating our PHP version, those apps started to crash.

Of course we will fix this issue in apps, but I was wonder why PHP changed this, as it seems to be accepted in other platforms.

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam This is not a duplicate, because his format is correct in PHP 7.1. [proof](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad27eef856f8e2d4bae037669a29e9279c26b0a2).

Comment: @PhilippMaurer an explanation could let us into a PHP bug, so yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see in [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/8e3260376c65b762a51eee7c30ab560dadefa1f6#diff-851fac022a0926b8a6dbe650a12e4f82L343) the `timezonemap.h` file was updated to remove the references to `brst` along with many other abbreviations.

The commit message reads:

> Update timezonemap.h, which needs to match the bundled TZ db

---

Digging deeper (thanks [@JamesThorpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076970/why-php-does-not-parse-brst-dates-anymore#comment83128912_48077511)) you can see the abbreviations were [introduced in July 1999](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/1999-July/010592.html) by Paul Eggert.  Notably he claims to have invented these himself:

> I invented the English-language abbreviations, and I also invented the other rows to be consistent with the -3:00 row.

[This tz commit](https://github.com/eggert/tz/commit/c9e6ef07cc6f1062ddd032c96c5172f403c0058f#diff-109e03a0a154807a82e70bef80657ebbL27) in December 2016 (again by Eggert) removes the abbreviations and replaces them with the following text:

> These tables use numeric abbreviations like -03 and -0330 for integer hour and minute UTC offsets.  Although earlier editions used alphabetic time zone abbreviations, these abbreviations were invented and did not reflect common practice.

Comment: Googling things through a bit, we end up [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1734967) _"Remove some invented abbreviations in ‘europe’"_ - possibly was extended to other "invented" abbreviations, and if we go all the way back to 1999, we find [this message](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/1999-July/010592.html): _"I invented the
English-language abbreviations"_ (for BRST).  Looks like the TZdb has had somewhat of a cleanup.

Comment: Looks crystal clear to me. Thank you for the answer.