# How to get date range of 7 days before and after of given date and populate in select - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, eloquent, date-range

I am trying to get date list of 7 dates before and after of a specific date in select field in laravel. 
For Example if a specific date is "2019-07-18", I want to populate date list from  "2019-07-11" to "2019-07-25" in select field.
Can anyone help me with code snippet for controller achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getAgoDays($specDay, $days, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $d = date('d', strtotime($specDay)); 
    $m = date('m', strtotime($specDay)); 
    $y = date('Y', strtotime($specDay));
    $dateArray = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$days; $i++) {
        $dateArray[] = '"' . date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($d-$i),$y)) . '"'; 
    }
    return array_reverse($dateArray);
}
function getBeforeDays($specDay, $days, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $d = date('d', strtotime($specDay)); 
    $m = date('m', strtotime($specDay)); 
    $y = date('Y', strtotime($specDay));
    $dateArray = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$days; $i++) {
        $dateArray[] = '"' . date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($d+$i),$y)) . '"'; 
    }
    return $dateArray;
}
```

use

```
$agoDays = getAgoDays('2019-07-18', 7, 'Y-m-d');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($agoDays);
echo '</pre>';
$agoDays = getBeforeDays('2019-07-18', 7, 'Y-m-d');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($agoDays);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks @Giang, I was able to get the desired results with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [carbon period](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period):

```php
$givenDate = "2019-07-18";
$dateMinusOneWeek = Carbon::parse($givenDate)->subWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$datePlusOneWeek = Carbon::parse($givenDate)->addWeek()->format('Y-m-d');

$period = CarbonPeriod::create(dateMinusOneWeek , datePlusOneWeek);

//You can iterate over the period
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

//Or convert the period to an array of dates
$dates = $period->toArray();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Mateus,

I am getting this error:
Exception
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (dateMinusOneWeek) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database

Comment: @Mysticalsam, Reffer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861317/datetime-timezone-not-found-in-database)