# Login using facebook account show error like this how can i do?

Tags: php, linux, date

Login using facebook account show error like this how can i do ?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(
): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required*
to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
 case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you
most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' f
or now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.' in /home/admin/we
b/example.com/public_html/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessToken.php on line 15
6 Exception: DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's tim
ezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_
default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you a
re still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifie
r. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to selec
t your timezone. in /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/src/Facebook/Authent
ication/AccessToken.php on line 156 Call Stack: 0.0034 234912 1. {main}() /home/
admin/web/example.com/public_html/facebook_sign.php:0 0.0201 306840 2. Facebook\
Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getAccessToken() /home/admin/web/example.co
m/public_html/facebook_sign.php:28 0.0310 311056 3. Facebook\Authentication\OAut
h2Client->getAccessTokenFromCode() /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/src/F
acebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php:255 0.0310 311520 4. Facebook\Au
thentication\OAuth2Client->requestAnAccessToken() /home/admin/web/example.com/pu
blic_html/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php:166 0.8581 363032 5. Face
book\Authentication\AccessToken->__construct() /home/admin/web/example.com/publi
c_html/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php:247 0.8581 363088 6. Faceboo
k\Authentication\AccessToken->setExpiresAtFromTimeStamp() /home/admin/web/exampl
e.com/public_html/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessToken.php:57 0.8585 363248 7
. DateTime->__construct() /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/src/Facebook/A
uthentication/AccessToken.php:156
```

Comment: Syntax error on line 26. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you [read this one ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466794/3282633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a timezone setting for your PHP.

**Add this to the php.ini:**

```
date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

Replace the `US/Central` with one of the viable timezones found here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thank a lot Marvin Fischer

Comment: No problem, if it worked, please set the answer as accepted

Comment: sure , but i have to wait for 5 minutes (stackoverflow show this text)