# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (22/03/1983) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

Tags: laravel, function, date, strtotime

I'm faced a problem in my function. In this function, I want to select the collaborator where date date birth is the date now. But the problem is that I have a error like:
In Creator.php line 80:

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (22/03/1983) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

I need help

```
public static function listCard(){

    $collaborateurs = Organigramme::whereMonth('date_de_naissance', now()->month)->get();

    $collaborateursConcernes = [];

    foreach ($collaborateurs as $collaborateur) {
        // $today= date('d/m/Y');

        $date_de_naissance = Carbon::parse($collaborateur->date_de_naissance);
        $date_de_naissance = strtotime($date_de_naissance);

        $today= date('d-m');
        $annif = date('d-m', $date_de_naissance);
        if($annif == $today ){

            $collaborateursConcernes[] = $collaborateur;

        }

    }

    return collect($collaborateursConcernes);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which line throw this error?

Comment: `collaborateur->date_de_naissance` is a `timestamp`/`datetime` field, or a `string` field?

Comment: The error comes when I set the command for sending a Mail.

Comment: collaborateur->date_de_naissance is a date field

Comment: try this `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $collaborateur->date_de_naissance)->format('d-m');`

Comment: You save my day Droid. God bless you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::\_\_construct(): Failed to parse time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466794/fatal-error-uncaught-exception-exception-with-message-datetime-construct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **Carbon** does not understand `d/m/Y` format. You can use :

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $collaborateur->date_de_naissance)->format('d-m');
```

Comment: Thank you Droid!